# JMeter GET Request: How to get parameter names from csv file

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-3.2

I'm building a JMeter project where I want to get parameter names from a CSVfile.

The number of parameters and the parameter names are both variable in this case.

example csv file:

```
var1,var2,var3,var4
1,2,3,4
11,22,33,44
```

example jmeter requests:

```
/endpoint?var1=1&var2=2&var3=3&var4=4
/endpoint?var1=11&var2=22&var3=33&var4=44
```

It's easy to do if the parameters were hard coded, but how do we configure jmeter if they were as column names in the CSV?

Answer (score 0):

Leave the [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) `Variable Names` field empty, it'll save the variable as the first line comma separated values, and in HTTP request use the variables:

```
/endpoint?var1=${var1}1&var2=${var2}&var3=${var3}&var4=${var4}
```

> if the variable name field empty, then the first line of the file is read and interpreted as the list of column names.

Comment: What if I have multiple csvs, each with different number of parameters?

Then how do I set those variable names as parameters for the requests, if I don't know their names? Also, how do I know at that point how many parameters there are?

Comment: You control the CSV, you control the variable names in CSV and in test, you should correlate it